# derivative of the permittivity tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Good evening,

If I derive $\partial_{k} \epsilon_{\mu i}E_{i} $ where $\epsilon_{\mu i}$ is the permittivity tensor, is it equal to $\epsilon_{\mu i} \partial_{k} E_{i} $? under what circumstances are these two expressions equal?

I need to do that step in order to show something, but I don't know if that's always the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permittivity is a tensor if the medium is anisotropic, while a scalar for isotropic medium.

For a homogeneous medium, the permittivity does not depend on the space point (is a constant), instead, in an inhomogeneous medium it will depend on $\vec{x}$.

This means that in your case you can take it out from the derivative if the medium is homogeneous. Otherwise you would have to use the Leibniz' rule.